# Is there a way to know what meaning the も particle has?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-も

The も particle has the meaning of

> also
>   too
>    words of similar weight
>    about (emphasizing an upper limit)
>   as much as
>   even
>   more
>   further
>   other
>   again

So depending where it's placed like before/after a subject/verb/adj/noun etc.

Can you determine based on that what meaning it has ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To some extent you can, but Japanese is a heavily context based language and it is context that is key to determining the appropriate translation of も.

Consider

> 今日{きょう}は車{くるま}が10台{だい}**も**売{う}れた。
>   I sold as many as ten cars today.

I don't think there's any ambiguity there since も comes after a counter. But what about

> 今日{きょう}は車{くるま}**も**売{う}れた。

It could be

> (I finally manged to sell the motorbike and) I **even** sold the car today.

or

> ( I sold the motorbike and) I **also** sold the car.

The more I think about it the more I find that these definitions of も merge into each other, **even** in English (in Japanese **and also** in English).

も is a very versatile and often quite confusing particle. You should post specific example sentences where you are having problems working out which meaning to use.