# Meaning of も in ３つ も

Tags: meaning, particles, particle-も

I've got this sentence that I'm not sure if it is grammatically correct:

> 今月、 大切な テスト が ３つ も あります

It supposedly translates to

> I have three important tests this month.

Why the も, though? The counter is 三つ, so then does the も mean "three tests *still to go*" (and the translation is slightly off)?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69513/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38258/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/91309/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97526/9831

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks for listing the links!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This も is the one of emphasis (definition 3 [here](https://jisho.org/search/mo)).  It has nothing to do with how many tests are yet to be taken.  So in this case it means "as many as".

The definition given is not *wrong*, per se, but it's definitely lacking this emphasis.  A better translation would be "I have as many as three tests this month", which, though correct, is not a typical way to express it in English.  The assumed feeling is that maybe they usually only have one, possibly two tests a month; but this month is three.

I think to get the point across without using awkward, forced dialog, it would be better understood with visual or audible emphasis.  Read as "I have ***three*** tests this month!!"; or spoken with clear emphasis on the word "three".

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful - very much appreciate the elaboration!