# も meaning in もう八日*も*何も食べていないんです。

Tags: particle-も

Here is the full sentence:

> すみませんが、水を下さいませんか。
> もう八日も何も食べていないんです。

I am still at the beginner level. From my understanding:

**もう** means already
**も** means also

Why add も after the もう八日?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69513/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/91309/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38258/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97526/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/98919/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an emphasis (cf. [も](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%82%82/#je-75042) #5), and add *as many as* in the example. As such, も can be dropped but perhaps it is better to add 間 (八日間{ようかかん}) to make it work adverbially.

Another example:

- 日本に来てもう10年経った 10 years have passed since I came to Japan
- 日本に来てもう10年も経った As many as 10 years have passed since I came to Japan